# How Not to use OCMockObjects in XCTesting iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xctest, ocmock

```
- (void)testMockDisplayBooksFromBookStoreMethod_callToRepositoryToFindAll_booksAreBoundToView 
{

    NSArray* books = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Moby Dick", @"The Grapes of Wrath", @"Tale of Two Cities", nil];

    id bookStoreRepository = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:@protocol(IBookStoreRepository)];
    [[[bookStoreRepository expect] andReturn:books] findAllBooks];

    id displayBooksView = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:@protocol(IDisplayBooksView)];
    [[displayBooksView expect] displayBooks:books];

    sut = [[BookListPresenter alloc] initWithBookStoreRepository:bookStoreRepository andDisplayBooksView:displayBooksView];
    [sut displayBooksFromBookstore];


    [bookStoreRepository verify];
    [displayBooksView verify];

}
```

My question is how do i test for protocols without using OCMock in XCTesting.
In the Above code ??

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but if you don't want mocking, you can create custom objects that implement the protocols.

Comment: how do i create a mock object for a protocol without using OCMockObject ?? Like in the code above

Comment: https://github.com/dgadd/iOSModelViewPresenter this is original code need ur help Philip.

Comment: + (id)mockForProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol  //                                               id xyz = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:@protocol(someProtocol)];

How do i re-write this without using mockProtocol or rather in XCTesting how do i test the above scenario without using OCMocks ??

Need sample code ? How do u customize the same ?

Comment: You don't unless you want to write your own mocking logic...and that's a bigger job than I would take on.  XCTesting doesn't have its own mock entities, which is why people use OCMock.

Comment: Why in the world would you write a unit test for an interface(protocol) which does not even have any implementation? The whole idea about writing unit test is to check if your methods/behaviors behave the way you expect and if any problems caused by by human error  in those method implementation, test will protect you and you will know the problem just by running tests.